# How can I make the font size of the status bar of my old app to match the system status bar in iOS 10?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an app developed for iOS 7, and since then I keep updating it for every iOS update till the current iOS 10 version.

I have found that the font size of status bar in my app is slightly larger than that of the system status bar and other newer apps, which make it look dated (Please see the first picture below).

How can I make the status bar of my app looks the same as other newer apps (second picture below)?

[image: Status bar my app with slightly larger font size]

[image: Status bar of from a newer app which font size is smaller]

Comment: Do you support the larger 4.7" and 5.5" iPhones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add a LaunchScreen.storyboard in your project, and set it to the "Launch Screen File", and your status bar might be in normal size.

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly! Both the status bar, navigation bar and tab bar shrink to their normal size. I am interested to know why setting the Launch Screen File makes such a difference.

Comment: But what if I must use Launch Images ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Change in **info.plist** the row View controller-based status bar appearance and set it to NO
2. Change in **appDelegate.swift** in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

`UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent`

3. Inside every view controller use this code for auto color support in status bar

   override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle
   {
      return .lightContent
   }